# undefined reference to `Class::Class()'

Tags: c++, gcc, gtk, g++, gtkmm

I am writing a GTKmm window program; the main window creates two buttons, one for English and one for Chinese. The user can click on the button to bring up a different window in the appropriate language. Currently I am having trouble initializing the multiple-item container inside the main window. It is an object of type MainWindowPane, which inherits Gtk::HBox.

When I try to make, the compiler issues the following error:

```
$ make 
g++ -g `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags` -c MainWindow.cpp  
g++  -g -o QPI_frontend main.o MainWindow.o StartButton.o `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --libs`  
MainWindow.o: In function `MainWindow':  
/home/dmurvihill/Documents/QPI_frontend/MainWindow.cpp:9: undefined reference to   `MainWindowPane::MainWindowPane()'  
/home/dmurvihill/Documents/QPI_frontend/MainWindow.cpp:9: undefined reference to  `MainWindowPane::MainWindowPane()'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: *** [QPI_frontend] Error 1
```

I am using the latest version of gcc with pkg-config to include the proper libraries. I am also a java person.

```
/*
 * MAIN_WINDOW.H
 * Responsible for creating "slave" RSED windows. Can create English or Chinese
 * versions of the demo, and can destroy them all with one click.
 */  
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H  
#define MAINWINDOW_H  

#include <gtkmm/window.h>

//#include "SlaveWindow.h"
#include "StartButton.h"
#include "MainWindowPane.h"

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    MainWindow();   
private:
    MainWindowPane pane;
//  std::list<SlaveWindowThread> windows;       // Keeps track of all windows that have been created thus far.
    void destroyAllWindows();           // Iterates through the linked list and destroys each window.
};
#endif      //ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

```
/* 
 * MAIN_WINDOW.CPP
 *
 */  
#include "MainWindow.h"  
#include "MainWindowPane.h"  
#include "StartButton.h"  

MainWindow::MainWindow()// : /*list,*/ pane(/*list*/)
{
    pane;
}

void MainWindow::destroyAllWindows()
{
    //gtk_widget_destroy(*this);
    // TODO: Destroy all the other windows too.
}
```

---

```
/*
 * MAIN_WINDOW_PANE.H
 */  
#ifndef MAINWINDOWPANE_H  
#define MAINWINDOWPANE_H  

#include <gtkmm/box.h>
#include <gtkmm/button.h>

//#include "SlaveWindow.h"
#include "StartButton.h"

class MainWindowPane : public Gtk::HBox
{
public:
    MainWindowPane(/*&(std::list)*/);   
private:
    StartButton englishButton;      // Used to create a new RSED demo screen.
    StartButton chineseButton;      // Used to create a new RSED demo in chinese.
//  std::list<SlaveWindow> windows;     // Keeps track of all windows that have been created thus far.
    void destroyAllWindows();       // Iterates through the linked list and destroys each window.
};
#endif      //ifndef MAINWINDOWPANE_H
```

---

```
/* 
 * MAIN_WINDOW.CPP
 *
 */  
#include "MainWindowPane.h"  
#include "StartButton.h"  

MainWindowPane::MainWindowPane(/*&(std::list)*/) : 
    englishButton(StartButton::ENGLISH/*,&(std::list)*/), 
    chineseButton(StartButton::CHINESE/*,&(std::list)*/)
{
    pack_start(englishButton);
    englishButton.show();
    pack_start(chineseButton);
    chineseButton.show();
}

void MainWindow::destroyAllWindows()
{
    //gtk_widget_destroy(*this);
    // TODO: Destroy all the other windows too.
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Undefined reference errors mean you either
forgot to write define the missing function
(by writing an implementation in the `.cpp` file),
or you forgot to link the appropriate object file or library into the final binary.

In this case, it's the later reason.
You need to include `MainWindowPane.o` in the linker command in your makefile:

```
g++  -g -o QPI_frontend main.o MainWindow.o StartButton.o `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --libs`
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                        you need MainWindowPane.o in here
```

Comment: That's it. Added the source to my makefile, and the code compiled successfully. Thanks!

Now, on to runtime debugging...

Comment: @ILikeFood, remember to hit the checkmark next to the answer that worked for you to accept the answer.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I tried to vote it up, too, but my acct is too new.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining that you are trying to call a default constructor for MainWindowPane that doesn't exist.

My guess is that MainWindowPane only defines ctors with parameters, and you are using it as a base class, *and* you either didn't define a ctor for the derived class, or the ctor you did define didn't call the base with parameters.

```
class MyDerived : public MainWindowPane
{
  public:
      MyDerived() {....}    // bad

      MyDerived(int x) : MainWindowPane(x)  // good
          {....}
```

UPDATE:

OK, ignore the above (written before you posted the code).  It seems to be complaining about this line"

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()// : /*list,*/ pane(/*list*/) 
{ 
    pane;     // Error HERE.
}
```

And I really have no idea what the purpose of that line is.  You are just referencing a data member, without doing anything with it.  It can probably be deleted.

UPDATE2:
`pane` will be default constructed if you do nothing:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{ 
}
```

Comment: I forgot to put in my code at first. Oops!
I've edited that in now. You can see that both the constructors I have defined the default constructor for MainWindowPane in the cpp file.

Hope the code makes it a little clearer. I feel like I'm making some trivial mistake on the syntax somewhere (something that's easy for Java programmers to slip into!).

Comment: That line was an attempt to call the default constructor for pane. I encounter a different error with pane();

I moved the attempted constructor call into the function body because I encountered the same error when I tried to call pane in the initializer list. I subsequently forgot to move it back. I get the same error with this code: ... 
MainWindow::MainWindow() : pane()
{
}
. 
With this code:
MainWindow::MainWindow() : pane {} ... 

I get this error:
MainWindow.cpp:9: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x' ...
Thanks for all your help so far.