# Why my C++ class definition fails?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Burrito.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
  Burrito b;
  return 0;
}
```

Burrito.h

```
#ifndef BURRITO_H
#define BURRITO_H

class Burrito{
    public:
      Burrito();
};

#endif
```

Burrito.cpp

```
#include "Burrito.h"
#include <iostream>

Burrito::Burrito(){

}
```

Compile & Link :

```
lzsb$ g++ main.cpp -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Burrito::Burrito()", referenced from:
      _main in ccVpCr0z.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lzsb$
```

Platform:

```
Mac OS 10.6.8

G++ : i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined reference to `Class::Class()'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506820/undefined-reference-to-classclass)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to compile the `Burrito.cpp` file as well. The compiler creates object files from each .cpp file and links them afterwards. This is where your call fails, because the linker can't find the referenced `Burrito` class in any of your object files. To fix your compiler call just add `Burrito.cpp`

```
g++ main.cpp Burrito.cpp -o main
```

Comment: Thx,but if i have lots of cpp files, that will be stupid to add them all. Then how to deal with it normally when there are lots of source files ?

Comment: @MrROY Depends how you prefer to work. If you are using and IDE like XCode (since your on OSX) or Eclipse or Kdevelop, these IDEs provide you a possibilities to manage the compiler calls. If you prefer to work with an simple editor I would recommend you to use a Makefile (Make is already installed on OSX if you have the buildutils). See here for an example Makefile, that compiles all .cpp sources in a directory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9789115/991425 . Then all you have to do is to call make in commandline in the directory with the sources and the Makefile.

Answer (score 4):

Your compile line should be:

g++ Burrito.cpp main.cpp -o main